# Is it possible to get Rails' find_in_batches functionality in an older 2.2.2 project with a plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Rails 2.2.2 didn't have find_in_batches functionality (or find_each).

Is there a plugin that provides this?  I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paginated_each` from [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) to achieve this. It can be used as a gem or a plugin.

For example:

```
MyClass.paginated_each(:per_page => 100) do |obj|

end
```

will load your objects in batches of 100.